# Android how to apply Listener on AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView Filtered Items

Tags: java, android

I have a `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` , i have also set an `adapter` on my `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` . But I need to `handle` an `event` in which no items(filtered items ) is shown in my `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` .
I just don't know how to `handle` this specific `event` i have also read the docs but its not that simple . So kindly help me out

For Eg:
Case 1:
Suppose my string array contains 2 items Apple , Android.
Now whenever the user will type "A"  , a drop-down list will appear showing filtered items 
In this particular case the drop-down list would have 2 items : Apple and Android

Case 2:
When the user types "Ax" , now the drop-down list will not appear. At this specific event , when there is no SUGGESTION or drop-down list shown . I need to display a toast.

Comment: do you want handle events when user clicks on item in autocompletetextView?

Comment: I have added a clear description now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called **onFilterComplete()** in *AutoCompleteTextView*.

```
  //count is the number of values computed by the filter
public void onFilterComplete (int count){

          if(count==0){
       //your code here 
     }
}
```

You should implement your code in the If block, As you want to handle things when the result is empty. ThankYou I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you adding a `TextWatcher` and check if [`isPopupShowing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#isPopupShowing()) in `afterTextChanged` like here**

```
autocompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         //---overridden beforeTextChanged and onTextChanged here----

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              if(!autocompleteTextView.isPopupShowing()){
                 //Handle the event here if no suggestions are available    
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no suggestions available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me , but "autocompleteTextView.isPopupShowing()" shows false if a single character is typed for the first time interaction with autocompletetextview. After the first time interaction, means second time interaction, it works fine

Comment: Will you make it clear ? I didn't get what you are saying.. It is prefixed with (**!**) actually.

Comment: I am printing the boolean value returned by autocompleteTextView.isPopupShowing() in afterTextChanged(..)

Comment: @ChrisRedField you can use [setThreshold(2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold(int)) method for that, and check `if(autocompleteTextView.getText().length() >2)` before checking `isPopupShowing`.

Comment: @ChrisRedField Then what happened ? Isn't that printed out ? I have just tested it fully and it's working very fine.

Comment: @ChrisRedField Didn't you even find this a little bit helpful to you, although I've tested this many times for you to make sure if it works or not.

Comment: Thank Shree Krishna, for helping me , but the way you told me isn't good.

Comment: do you mean the way of answering isn't good or something else. If so then your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I will give you a detailed explanation , just give me at max 2 days

Comment: @ChrisRedField bro, I've waited 2 days.